# Select all queries with reference id in a chain

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have this table which I would like to store a chain of records.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    id INT,
    unique_id varchar,
    reference_id varchar,
);
```

I want to implement SQL query for MariDB which prints all records by id with all records with reference_id. Something like this:

```
| id | unique_id | reference_id |   |   |
|----|-----------|--------------|---|---|
| 43 | 55544     |              |   |   |
| 45 | 45454     | 43           |   |   |
| 66 | 55655     | 45           |   |   |
| 78 | 88877     | 66           |   |   |
| 99 | 454       | 33           |   |   |
```

I would like when I select record 66 to get all up and down transactions because each other are using id which points to them. How I can implement this using Recursive CTE? Is there a better way?

Expected result for record with unique_id 66:

```
| id | unique_id | reference_id |   |   |
|----|-----------|--------------|---|---|
| 43 | 55544     |              |   |   |
| 45 | 45454     | 43           |   |   |
| 66 | 55655     | 45           |   |   |
| 78 | 88877     | 66           |   |   |
```

I tried this but above rows are not printed.

```
select @ref:=id as id, unique_id, reference_id
from mytable
join (select @ref:=id from mytable WHERE reference_id=@ref or id = 66)tmp
where reference_id=@ref
```

[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4eLobbrosJfA6EPqsErBDM/0)

Can you give me hand to find a solution?

EDIT: Attempt with CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select t.*
      from mytable
      where t.id = 66
      union all
      select t.*
      from cte join
           mytable t
           on cte.id = t.reference_id
     )
select *
from cte;
```

I get error `Unknown table 't'`

Comment: You should be using recursive CTEs for this.  Whether your database supports them depends on the version of MySQL/MariaDB that you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated the post to show also what I tried with CTE. I suppose tat I can use CTE in JPA native query? Can you give me hand how to implement properly this query?

Comment: Here is what I tried https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pyh6ALLoZ5KnuZ4ZEd9Bhj/0

Comment: Just at the alias `t` after the first reference to `my_table`.

Comment: Can you paste official answer please so I can rate it?

Comment: . . Instead I'm voting to close as a simple typographical error.

Comment: Which line is this `Just at the alias t after the first reference to my_table`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with recursive CTE. You can try the below query.

```
select t.id, t.unique_id, @uid := t.reference_id reference_id
from (select * from mytable order by id desc) t
join (select @uid := 66) tmp
where t.id = @uid or reference_id=66
```

Comment: Thanks, It's working. Can you give some advice how to fix `Unknown table 't'` into the CTE example that I have pasted?

Comment: Just add the alias `t` in 3rd line like `....select t.* from mytable t...`

Comment: It's working, thanks. But it's limited to below records. I can't get all referenced id's @Gordon Linoff can you advice please?